# neo4j-you do not have permission to load a database--is Neo4j running as a different user?

Tags: database, neo4j

1. I want to use the following command will ResourceOrachestrationCase database import into neo4j,

   [The result was an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqDXy.png)
2. Somebody says that it may be because the current user's roles is not admin. But my neo4j has only one user, "neo4j," and its roles also is "admin."

   [my neo4j has only one user, "neo4j," and its roles also is "admin."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3ZSc.png)

[Link 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqDXy.png)
[Link 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3ZSc.png)
[Link 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEM5q.png)
[Link 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wQsb.png)
[Link 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njcfs.png)

Comment: the comment is "neo4j-admin load --from=D:\neo4j\neo4j-community\data\databases\ResourceOrchestrationCase.db --database=ResourceOrchestrationCase.db --force

Comment: This command has been used successfully once before

Comment: the error is "you do not have permission to load a database--is Neo4j running as a different user?"

Comment: The operating system is Windows